# taborder hint in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Below is the code extract from visualforce guide

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Account: {!Account.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Details" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" taborderhint="4"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Website}" taborderhint="3"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}" taborderhint="2"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" taborderhint="1"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In here,taborderhint is in reverse order.My issue is when i land on page ,automatically the very first field is being selected(which has the taborderhint = 4)..Now if i click TAB controls goes to the global search (with skip to main content link highlighted)

Is this the expected behaviour?If so is there any way to focus on a particular input field,as opposed to very first being focused all the time

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to set the focus to a particular field.  Add this script text to the end of your page (after the field, and before you close the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('{!$Component.yourComponentId}').focus();
</script>
```

Something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Edit Account: {!Account.Name}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Details" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" taborderhint="4"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Website}" taborderhint="3"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}" taborderhint="2"/>
        <apex:inputField id="aRev" value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" taborderhint="1"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('{!$Component.aRev}').focus();
</script>
```